# How to prepare a dataset of images to train and test tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, windows-10

I am using Windows 10 pro, Visual Studio 10, Python 3.6.2rc1 and Tensorflow. I am trying to build a convolutional neural network (CNN) to classify images of fruits with Tensorflow. I have only two fruits, pineapple and banana. It's less than a week I am working with python and this is my first experience.

I made 2 folders, one for training images with same size images with jpg format, and another for test images also with jpg format. I have also two txt one for training and one for test. As an example, data in my training set is like this:

```
image001 banana

image002 pineapple
```

I don't know how to feed these data into a sample network. I used the exact network from

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.2/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/layers/cnn_mnist.py

and read the tutorial at tensorflow for both reading data and the explanation of the above code at:

https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/layers

My biggest problem is I don't understand how MNIST is fed into this network and couldn't really figure out by using what is written at tensorflow site in programmers_guide/reading_data.

I would really appreciate if you can give me more concrete guidance regarding what I need to do to feed the images of these two folders and the two text files into the above network. Also since I'm quite new to python, I am not very familiar with it yet, to know what I must import for doing so. Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are the lines where the MNIST data is fed in:

```
# Load training and eval data
mnist = learn.datasets.load_dataset("mnist")
train_data = mnist.train.images  # Returns np.array
train_labels = np.asarray(mnist.train.labels, dtype=np.int32)
eval_data = mnist.test.images  # Returns np.array
eval_labels = np.asarray(mnist.test.labels, dtype=np.int32)
```

The `learn.datasets.load_dataset`is a convenience function that loads the MNIST data into the necessary variables that are then used here for training:

```
mnist_classifier.fit(
  x=train_data,
  y=train_labels,
  batch_size=100,
  steps=20000,
  monitors=[logging_hook])
```

You have to adapt the first code block to load in your images to `train_data` and the corresponding labels to `train_labels`.

Just a recommendation: Start with Keras as the high level API on top of Tensorflow. It´s a lot easier (in my opinion) and much more flexible.

This tutorial from the maker of Keras might be a very good starting point for you: https://blog.keras.io/building-powerful-image-classification-models-using-very-little-data.html

It´s exactly about classifying two classes of images (cats vs dogs).